Proof of Krull schmidt theorem
I have been trying to understand the proof of this theorem from the book "Algèbres et modules." Cours et exercices. 
I've been trying for a while, but I haven't been able to understand the last part of the theorem. Why do we have that isomorphism?.
Thanks for the help :)

First let me fix some notation. Let $\iota,\iota',\pi,\pi'$ be the inclusions and the canonical projections associated to the decomposition $M=N_1\oplus N_1'$. Note that, in particular $\iota=q_1$ and $\pi=p_1$.
Note that the maps
$$
\varphi:M_1\oplus M_1'\to M, \quad \begin{pmatrix} x\\ x' \end{pmatrix}\mapsto q(x)+q'(x')
$$
and
$$
\psi:M\to N_1\oplus N_1', \quad x\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
\pi(x) \\ \pi'(x)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
are both module isomorphisms (as you can easily verify), where we regard the direct sums as external direct sums (or equivalently, direct product of modules). Then you obtain the isomorphism $f=\psi\circ \varphi:M_1\oplus M_1'\to N_1\oplus N_1'$ given by
$$
f\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ x'
\end{pmatrix} = \psi(q(x)+q'(x')) = \begin{pmatrix} \pi(q(x)+q'(x')) \\ \pi'(q(x)+q'(x')) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \pi q(x)+\pi q'(x') \\ \pi' q(x)+\pi' q'(x') \end{pmatrix}
$$
and we can re-write this in matrix form as
$$
f\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ x'
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\pi q & \pi q' \\
\pi' q & \pi' q'
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ x'
\end{pmatrix},
$$
so if we define $f_{11}=\pi q$ (which was already defined), $f_{12}=\pi q'$, $f_{21}=\pi' q$ and $f_{22}=\pi' q'$, we obtain that the isomorphism $f$ has the matrix representation
$$
f = \begin{pmatrix}
f_{11} & f_{12}\\
f_{21} & f_{22}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now, for the other part, note that the morphism $g_1:N_1\oplus N_1'\to N_1\oplus N_1'$ given by the matric representation (recall that $f_{11}$ is an isomorphism)
$$
g_1 := \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-f_{21}f_{11}^{-1} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is an isomorphism. Explicitly we have
$$
g_1 \begin{pmatrix}
x\\ x'
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
-f_{21}f_{11}^{-1}(x)+x'
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and you can easily prove from this that $\ker(g_1)=0$ and $g_1$ is surjective. Similarly the morphism $g_2:M_1\oplus M_1'\to M_1\oplus M_1'$ given by the matrix representation
$$
g_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -f_{11}^{-1}f_{12}\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is an isomorphism. Thus the composition $g=g_1fg_2:M_1\oplus M_1'\to N_1\oplus N_1'$ is an isomorphism. But a simple computation shows that $g$ has the matrix representation given in the picture, so $g$ is represented by a diagonal matrix, and it is easy to prove that a diagonal matrix is an isomorphism if and only if each entry in the diagonal is an isomorphism:
In general, if a homomorphism $h:A\oplus B\to C\oplus D$ is represented by a matrix
$$
h = \begin{pmatrix}
h_1 & 0 \\
0 & h_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
we can prove that $h$ is injective (respectively surjective) if and only if $h_1:A\to C$ and $h_2:B\to D$ are injective (resp. surjective). For example, if $h$ is injective, let $a\in \ker(h_1)$,
$$
h\begin{pmatrix}
a \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} h_1(a) \\ h_2(0) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and since $h$ is injective, $\begin{pmatrix} a\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = 0$ so that $a=0$ and $\ker(h_1)=0$. Similarly $h_2$ is injective. The converse is similar and surjectivity is left for you.
Thus for the proof, you obtain that $f_{22}-f_{21}f_{11}^{-1}f_{12}:M_1'\to N_1'$ is an isomorphism.

Thank you very much for your explanation! Now everything is very clear to me :)
